# Ты — ступай, я — ?

Tags: словообразование

Интересно, в повелительном наклонении — и "ступай", и "иди". А при этом я — только "иду". А куда девалось "я — *ступаю*?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Мне кажется, что возникла некоторая путаница в значениях. "Ступай" = "иди". А вот "ступать" и "идти" не одно и то же.!

Answer (score 4):

Никуда не делось: Я осторожно ступаю на траву... Я не хожу, а ступаю по земле, выбирая, куда поставить ногу. А ещё есть я хожу, шагаю, наступаю - всё зависит от значения слова-какое нужно, то и выбираем.

Answer (score 0):

> А куда девалось "я — ступаю?"

Куда-куда...
Смотреть надо под ноги, тогда и вопросов не будет, куда...